# SQL Server Numeric data type turns into Short_Text in MS Access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

We have SQL Server 2008 running on a server. I linked the MS Access 2013 to tables of one of the SQL Server's database via ODBC (SQL Server Native Client 10). Everything seemed OK till now, when I realized that one data type has changed while it was coming from the SQL Server to Access.

The data type in SQL Server is `Numeric(38,8)` yet in MS Access it became `Short_text`. Any ideas why is this happened and what should I do to tackle this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Could you present sample data that has been transformed to Short_text and sample cell value from Ms-Access Numeric column (with decimal places)? I think it could be localization settings (number formats difference and assumption made)

Comment: interesting, I just tried it and access could not display any data correctly. I receive ODBC call failed. However, when I try to use data filters I can see my data in the filter menu.

Comment: data appeared after converting the table to local table, it seems something went wrong while connecting to my odbc file

Comment: I cannot really put data out here. The data is shown as ".0000000" for value as zero in Ms-Access - obviously it shows as 0.000000 in SQL Server Studio. I guess as next stage I will try to use SQL Server Native Client 11 in the ODBC connection setup, see how that performs...

Comment: @Tamas, it seems you did not check my answer, just change precision in sql to 28 and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you selected a number for precision which is 38 that is larger than the maximum acceptable precision by MS Access 2013 which is 28

So, It failed to map it to Number data type in access, that's why it was converted to short_text

However, I see this is a bug in ODBC, as it was supposed to provide a warning or show something in the log.
But when I tried it myself, I found the log is empty

Comment: mGouda, thanks for the answer - I will check it tomorrow when I am back to work...it sounds as a reasonable explanation though...

Comment: mGouda - you were right. I just checked it and it seems that Access gets a bit confused with high precision SQL data types. Thanks!